# Merge two dataframe to mimic 'select * from tablea, tableb'

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge two dataframes together to mimic 'select * from A, B', for example,
table A will look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
table_a = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A', 'B']})
```

table B will look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
table_b = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2], 'y':[3,4]})
```

What I want to have is

```
import pandas as pd
table_c = pd.DataFrame({'id':['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                        'x': [1,2,1,2], 'y':[3,4,3,4]})
```

i.e. duplicate A and B table_b.shape[0] times and append it.

I believe there are multiple ways to do it. For example,

```
a = table_b.loc[np.tile(table_b.index.values, table_a.shape[0])]
b = table_a.loc[np.repeat(table_a.index.values, table_b.shape[0])]
a['id'] = b['id'].values
```

Is there any other better way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.DataFrame([
    d1 + d2
    for d1 in zip(*map(table_a.get, table_a))
    for d2 in zip(*map(table_b.get, table_b))
], columns=table_a.columns.append(table_b.columns))
```

Comment: :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/52278086